# Unknown ? shape keras Deep learning

Tags: python, input, keras, deep-learning, shapes

I’m trying to implement a deep learning model with Keras. Yet I have a problem with an unknown shape implementation. I was looking for a similar error but didn’t find it.

Here is my code.

```
Xhome = dataset[:,32:62]

Xaway = dataset[:,62:92]

Ywin = dataset[:,2:32]

Yscorehome = dataset[:,0]

Yscoreaway = dataset[:,1]

home = Input(shape=(2431,30))

print(home)

Tensor("input_6:0", shape=(?, 2431, 30), dtype=float32)
```

---

[image: diagram]

Ask me if you need more information to understand.

Comment: Are you trying to find what value should replace "?" in the final line?

Comment: I just don't want to have this None column and to only have a shape of (2431,30)

Comment: do you have 2431 samples with 30 features each?

Comment: how does your input look like? are those images? If your data has a dimensionality of 30, then the shape should be `(?,30)`, as the number of samples you feed to the network should be variable.

Comment: It's text i have encoded it. Yes it's 2431 row for 30 columns.

Answer (score 3):

The unknown shape (? or None) is not an error - it means that this dimension is variable instead of fixed sized.

The first dimension in a Keras model is always the batch size and therefore gets the shape `None`. This allows you to use variable batch sizes. When you define your input shape in a Keras layer the batch size dimension is ignored and you only define the shape of each sample. In your case, the input shape `(2431,30)` means that each sample has this shape. If you want 2431 to be the batch size, you should instead use `(30,)` as input shape.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Even with Input(shape=(30,)) i got shape (None,30). Then when I fit the model i have this error:                                                         'When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect thetensors to have a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: (None, 30)'

Comment: The first dimension of your input shape will always be None, so (None, 30) is as expected. It sounds like you are trying to fit your model on a tensor (maybe the input layer?) but you should fit it on your actual data (i.e. a numpy array of shape (batch_size, 30)).

Comment: Thanks for your help i now understand more how neural network works!